# mp3 Download Ionic Framework | Android | HTML5

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe, ionic-framework

I am working on ionic framework for android .

It simply contains an Iframe to embed a website in a blank project.
This is the website http://www.ultrayoutube.com/ANDROID/#/wanna.

I am facing two problems

1. Making Iframe equal to size of screen
   I want Iframe to be equal to the size of window . I am using `<iframe src="http://www.ultrayoutube.com/ANDROID/#/wanna" style="width:100%; height:100%;" ></iframe>`

   But iframe only takes 1/2 of screen in emulator
2. When the user searches for the song he must be able to download it by clicking download mp3

I have gone through some plugins as file transfer plugins but they all need a download link to download something . I want it that when the user clicks on button download mp3 , that link is automatically passed to the plugin and is downloaded to user's cell phone .

Answer (score 0):

on Document Head try to initialise your file transfer plugin

```
function onDeviceReady() {
console.log('deviceready');
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function(fileSystem) {
            window.fs = fileSystem;
            window.fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            window.fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                    var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                    console.log(perc + '%');
                    $('.progress-bar').css({width: perc + '%'});
                }
            };
            window.fs.root.getDirectory('Download', {create: true},       function(dirEntry) {
                window.downloadFolder = dirEntry;
            });
        },
        function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }
);
```

}

Change : script.js

```
app.run(function($rootScope, downloader, alertService) {
$rootScope.fs = window.fs;
$rootScope.downloadFolder = window.downloadFolder;
$rootScope.fileTransfer = window.fileTransfer;

$rootScope.messages = {}
```

...

```
$rootScope.saveContent = function(url) {
    var uri = encodeURI(url);
    $rootScope.fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            $rootScope.downloadFolder.toURL() + "/" + url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
            function(entry) {
                console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                console.log("download error target " + error.target);
            }
    );
};
```

...

Comment: can you just explain what is script.js ?